# How to find rowindex of a datatable into another datatable?

Tags: c#

I am using C#. I have two data tables and i want to find the rows of first data table into second data table.
Example.
First data table's data:

```
1  inam
2  sohan
```

Second data tables's data:

```
3  ranjan
1  inam
2  sohan
```

Now i want to know the index of first two rows of first data table into second data table.

Please help guys.
Any answer or advice

Best Regards

Comment: You should consider tagging this story with the data access and database technologies you plan to use.

Comment: Why not use for loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following extension method which returns the first index of a "sub-sequence":

```
// I've used String.Join to get something that is comparable easily
// from the ItemArray that is the object-array of all fields
IEnumerable<string> first = table1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => string.Join(",",r.ItemArray));  // 
IEnumerable<string> second = table2.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => string.Join(",", r.ItemArray));

int index = second.IndexOfSequence(first, null);  // 1
```

Here the extension:

```
public static int IndexOfSequence<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> input, IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (!sequence.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must not be empty", "sequence");

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    }
    int index = -1;
    int firstIndex = -1;
    bool found = false;
    TSource first = sequence.First();

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = input.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator2 = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator2.MoveNext();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                index++;
                found = comparer.Equals(enumerator.Current, enumerator2.Current);
                if (found && firstIndex == -1) firstIndex = index;
                if (found && !enumerator2.MoveNext())
                    return firstIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

tested with this sample data:

```
var table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table1.Columns.Add("Name");
var table2 = table1.Clone();

table1.Rows.Add(1, "inam");
table1.Rows.Add(2, "Sohan");

table2.Rows.Add(3, "ranjan");
table2.Rows.Add(1, "inam");
table2.Rows.Add(2, "Sohan");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have much volume this might work....

```
var tableOneIndex = -1;
var tableTwoIndex = -1;

foreach (var tableOneRow in tableOne.Rows)
{
    tableOneIndex++;

    foreach (var tableTwoRow in tableTwo.Rows)
    {
        tableTwoIndex++;

        if (tableOneRow["name"].ToString() == tableTwoRow["name"].ToString())
        {
             // Do whatever you wanted to do with the index values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Name is not the only column in the table. Also all rows must have the same fields in the same order not only one.

Comment: _"Now i want to know the index of first two rows of first data table into second data table."_ So OP wants to find the first index in the second table where **all rows** from the first table have the same fields. So if the second table has 100 rows and the first table has 10 rows, these ten rows must be part of the larger table and OP wants the first index. Look at his (small) example.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, this should suffice:

```
// Create and populate data tables
DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

DataRow row1 = dataTable1.NewRow();
row1["Name"] = "Inam";

DataRow row2 = dataTable1.NewRow();
row2["Name"] = "Sohan";

dataTable1.Rows.Add(row1);
dataTable1.Rows.Add(row2);

DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

DataRow row3 = dataTable2.NewRow();
row3["Name"] = "Ranjan";

DataRow row4 = dataTable2.NewRow();
row4["Name"] = "Inam";

DataRow row5 = dataTable2.NewRow();
row5["Name"] = "Sohan";

dataTable2.Rows.Add(row3);
dataTable2.Rows.Add(row4);
dataTable2.Rows.Add(row5);

// Loop through rows in first table
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable1.Rows)
{
    int rowIndexInSecondTable = 0;

    // Loop through rows in second table
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // Check if the column values are the same
        if (row["Name"] == dataTable2.Rows[i]["Name"])
        {
            // Set the current index and break to stop further processing
            rowIndexInSecondTable = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // The index of the row in the second table is now stored in the rowIndexInSecondTable variable, use it as needed, for example, writing to the console
    Console.WriteLine("Row with name '" + row["Name"] + "' found at index " + rowIndexInSecondTable.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Name is not the only column in the table. Also all rows must have the same fields in the same order not only one.

Comment: That's not the case, this will work regardless of number of fields or field order. I use the name of the column instead of the column index, the only thing I access by index is the row.

Comment: But you break as soon one row has the same name. All rows in the smaller table must have the same fields as a part of the larger table. Apart from that, you're only comparing one field instead of all.

Comment: Alright, well I clearly failed to glean that from the question. I'll let the OP decide.